# Can you export Material themes in Sketch directly to React?

Tags: reactjs, material-design

I am using material.io 's sketch plugin and a variation of the theme "fortnightly". Aside from hand coding all the designs in React, is there a way to export components directly?

material-ui doesn't inherit any of material.io's themes

Comment: I don’t think those two things are related, so probably no.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but where do you download the fortnightly theme, how can I „use it“ as you say?

Comment: material.io Sketch plugin

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there're a few solutions to sketch-to-react conversion tools, we also implement our own one.
But until now, there are no related conversion tools which recognize the theme or design system of Sketch into code.

From our own solution, nearest solution is to mark a group as component to reuse the CSS styles (theme) across screens and pages.
We are working on how to leverage the design system of Sketch into reuseable and shared react components. We will let users to mark common styles in "design guidelines" artboard in Sketch file, currently it's only direction we can leverage design guidelines into reused CSS styles as theme.